Django - Assigning employee to projects on various dates (durations)
How can I assign each employee (many) on projects (many) while also tracking the dates when they were assigned and removed from each project? I realize this is a ManyToManyField type of relationship in Django where:
class Project(models.Model):
    projectname=models.CharField()

class Employee(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField()
    lastname = models.CharField()
    start_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True) #because we don't know this all the time
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project)

But I hope to be able to generate an app where I can both view each employee where they are on projects currently and where they've been in the past. The tricky part here consists in me possibly sending employees back to the same project after having taken them off for a couple of weeks to perform on another project. Please forgive me for this is my first post/question on this site and haven't quite grasped the proper format for asking questions.
I simply tried adding a start_date and an end_date for each employee but I do not think that is working properly as I have a feeling those dates are overwritten every time I modify Employee. I am missing something and hope to find others more experienced that would see the easy solution here.

As a start, you probably want a separate Assignment table with employee_id, start_date, end_date and project_id.

you can use custom through model.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships
class Project(models.Model):
    projectname=models.CharField()

class pm(models.Model):
  p = models.ForeignKey(Project)
  e = models.ForeignKey('Employee')
  date_start = models.DateField()
  date_end = models.DateField()

class Employee(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField()
    lastname = models.CharField()
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, through=pm)


e = Employee.objects.get({query})
p = Project.objects.get({query2})
pm(p=p, e=e, date_start={date}).save()

e.projects.all()
p.employee_set.all()


Thank you all very much. I will give these answers a try right now.
